# Why don't FontWeights work in DrawText/DrawingVisual?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a drawText field, and I am using FontWeights.Bold, if I change it to SemiBold, Medium or ExtraBold, it doesn't seem to make a difference. For some reason, every bold-type is the same level of weight. The problem I have is normal weight is too light, and bold weight is too heavy, so I want to use SemiBold; but it doesn't make a diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all fonts are created equal.  The fonts themselves define what kinds of "things" (weight, width, slope), and WPF does its best to most closely match what you are looking for.

Take a look at [**this whitepaper**](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-02-24-90-36/WPF-Font-Selection-Model.pdf) about the font matching/selection process used by WPF.  It is on [**a blog from Mikhail Leonov**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2007/04/23/wpf-font-selection-model.aspx), a developer on the WPF text team.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this just as an example

```
 System.Drawing.Font newFont = new Font
 (
   "Verdana", 10f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, 
   System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, 178, false
 );
```

Would also love to see some of your sample code to make sure that I am on the same page as you are in regards to the issue that you are having..